# Undefined Behaviour Bug : Changes to a member variable visible only from some contexts

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, embedded

I have a struct, it is equivalent to this:

```
    struct Interface
    {
        static inline TransmitData TXData{ nullptr, 0 };
        //
        static void TransmitContinue() noexcept
        {
            packet_t packet{ IN_Id };
            //
            if ( auto tx{ TXData.Consume( packet_t::Capacity() ) }; packet.Assign( tx ) )
            {
                // Point E
                // A transmission is triggered here with the tx variable above.
            }
        }
        static bool TransmitComplete() noexcept
        {
            TXData.PopFront( packet_t::Capacity() );
            //
            if ( TXData.Empty() )
            {
                // Point A
            }
            else
            {
                // Point B
                TransmitContinue();
            }
            return true;
        }
        static bool Transmit( TransmitData data ) noexcept
        {
            if ( TXData.Empty() )
            {
                // Point C
                TXData = data;
                TransmitContinue();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Point D
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
```

The implementation of TransmitData::Empty is as follows:

```
    ALWAYS_INLINE constexpr bool Empty() const noexcept
    {
        return ( Size() == 0 ) or ( Data() == nullptr );
    }
```

The implementation of TransmitData::Size is as follows:

```
    ALWAYS_INLINE constexpr size_type Size() const noexcept
    {
        return m_Length;
    }
```

The implementation of TransmitData::PopFront is as follows (count is the number of bytes to pop):

```
    constexpr TransmitData & PopFront(size_type count = 1) noexcept
    {
        auto c{ std::min(Size(), count) };
        m_Data      += c;
        m_Length    -= c;
        return *this;
    }
```

The implementation of TransmitData::Consume is as follows:

```
    ALWAYS_INLINE constexpr TransmitData Consume( std::size_t index ) const noexcept
    {
        return { m_Data, std::min( index, Size() ) };
    }
```

The function "Transmit" is run inside int main().

The function "TransmitComplete" is run from a hardware interrupt.

The "TransmitData" structure is very similar to std::string_view, with some additional functionality. The length variable contained within the structure is not volatile.

**The sequence of calls is as follows:**

1. int main() calls the Transmit function
2. Point C is reached, TX data is assigned with the parameter data.
3. Point E is reached, a transmission is triggered.
4. An interrupt calls the TransmitComplete function
   Point A is reached ( TX data is empty ) after a packet is sent. In this problem case this is correct, the TXData is actually empty after the Pop function.
5. Main then sends more data
6. Trigger transmit is then called again, here is the issue.
7. Despite transmit complete indicating that TXData is empty the next call and every single proceeding call to Transmit indicates that TXData is full. 
   This is strange because:

   1. TXData is only loaded by "Point C" this happens only once
   2. It is only removed by "TransmitComplete"
   3. Reaching PointA shows that the TXData is empty. This happens well before Transmit is called again.
   4. The second call to Transmit indicates TXData is full (By reaching point D), without loading any more data.

**System where problem exists**

This is on a single core ARM M0 application with only one thread of execution (the main one). The interrupt functions always complete before a followup transmit is called.

I'm using GCC 8.2.

**Current working theory**

GCC is instantiating two instances of the counter variable. It is not optimising it to a constant because the Empty member function indicates changes in the length variable in both the TransmitComplete and Transmit functions.

The strange thing here is that changes to the length variable from within the Transmit function are visible to the TransmitComplete function. However, changes to the length variable from the TransmitComplete function are not visible to the Transmit function.

**NOTE**
If I change the m_Length  member variable in the TransmitData structure (similar to string_view) to volatile the code works as intended, without issue.

The only change for the above is changing the TransmitData member m_Length from:

```
size_type   m_Length{ 0u };
```

To:

```
size_type volatile m_Length{ 0u };
```

I don't believe the length variable should require volatile as all changes to the variable are done in code and should be visible to the compiler.

Putting volatile on the length member hinders optimisations elsewhere in the program, I'm looking to avoid it because the penalty is pretty high.

**Question**

Does anybody know why this bug could be occurring? 
Does anybody know how the symptoms described above could be possible?
Am I doing something silly (likely)?

Comment: This is all undefined behaviour (from a standards point of view), interrupt handlers are not allowed to do anything other than set an atomic flag.  The compiler may compile the program on assumption that variable values will not change randomly outside of the thread of execution

Comment: What is the proposed solution?
The interrupt here only sets an integer. Do I make the length variable an atomic?

Comment: `volatile on the length member hinders optimisations` - so make only hand-picked accesses volatile, not the whole variable. Also this is interrupt, I assume you block interrupts when reading from the variable. Compiler can reorder the accesses and give you invalid value.

Comment: @KamilCuk huh? either the variable is volatile or it isn't

Comment: @M.M  I mean OP should `*(volatile typeof(m_Length)*)&m_Length = the_lenth` in interrupt and in hand-picked locations in the source where `volatile` is needed to make the program work.  If `volatile` seems to fix the problem and it hinders optimization for OP, then I say - pick only those places that you really need to access the variable using volatile specifier. It's just like `READ_ONCE` and `WRITE_ONCE` macros in kernel

Comment: @KamilCuk that's not well-defined  (but might work for particular compilers) . IMO a cleaner solution would be to use an atomic flag

Comment: What about accessing the TransmitData from a volatile pointer, that way the value (the pointer) accessed by the interrupt isn't changing?

Comment: @KamilCuk "_It's just like READ_ONCE and WRITE_ONCE macros in kernel_" You meant to write: "just like the code that the (GNU) C code worked only by accident in linux and that GCC never said they would support".

Comment: volatile should be used to fix the bug but it doesn't help with race conditions. See this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102

Comment: Yeah, the m_Length needs have atomic writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `main` function is very simple. The compiler is able to analyse the full control flow and see that nothing in `main` can change `m_length` once it was set in the first call to `Transmit`. So it assumes that the value of `m_length` holds through the entire execution time, and thus all the following comparisions of `m_length` against zero are false.

This explains why adding `volatile` solves the problem: it forces the compiler to re-access the `m_length` each time it is evaluated.

Comment: Interesting, thanks
Do you see any problem with me doing this:
https://pastebin.com/nNYfnLi7
The volatile on the pointer inhibits the optimiser from removing the pointer and because the pointer might change the data must be re-read on each write like a volatile.

Comment: To make a short answer, all variables that are shared between interrupt and normal context must be volatile. Addressing only the write problem with a volatile pointer is incorrect. It might or might not work depending on the optimisations the compiler is doing. You can work with non volatile copies of the volatile variable if you need to accelerate some steps but you will need to update them manually.

Comment: If the pointer is volatile and its underlying data can change. Wouldn't the compiler need to re-read data each time it is accessed, because each time it is accessed it could be different?